# What is being said about Samson and his hair in Judges 16:22?

Tags: judges

Shortly after Samson's hair is cut, the author says that *'it began to grow again'*. I assume that the author is saying Samson's hair started to grow back immediately after it was cut. If this is true, what is the author trying to convey about Samson and his hair?  Why even mention this?

**Judges 16:22 (KJV)**

> Howbeit the hair of his head began to grow again after he was shaven.

Answer (score 2):

[Judges 16:22](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Judges_16:22?&version=KJV&interface=print), which mentions Samson's hair growing back after being shaved off, is a reference to the earlier verse [17](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Judges_16:17?&version=KJV&interface=print), where Samson naively confides to his Philistine wife [Delilah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delilah) that his physical strength lies in his (uncut) hair, thus preparing the events described in verses [29-30](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Judges_16:29-30?&version=KJV&interface=print), wherein the biblical hero will need all of his God-given strength back, so as to be able to break down the pillars of the house in which many Philistines were gathered, thereby causing the deaths of many enemies and oppressors of God's chosen people Israel.

Comment: Why is this reference to verse 17 needed? The reader already knows the secret of Samson's strength. What does verse 22 add to the narrative? Isn't Samson's prayer in verse 28 sufficient reason for God to return him his strength even without a full head of hair? The OP's question is not an easy one to answer.

Comment: If you really think so, then perhaps consider voting to delete this answer. It is a weak answer in its current state.

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahim: If by *reader* you mean the OP, then it most certainly did *not* seem to me personally that *that* is what he is *actually* asking. But if by any chance I am wrong on this, the OP *himself* can correct my misreading of his question by way of a *simple* comment. If however you refer to the reader in general, then, given the utterly non-Spartan abundance of repetitions throughout Scripture, I would have to say that there is no particularly deep reason for it. As for your last question, I am not entirely sure if the ancient Jews shared such a Scholastic understanding of God.